# Python: How do I assign variables in a list to a string, then add that string to a different list?

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

## Ok so here's the problem

```
for lst in tupleList:
        tempList = lst[2].split(",")
        for number in tempList:
                number = number + number
        salaryList.append(number)
    print(salaryList)
```

tupleList is a tuple containing lists, at index[2] of each list within the tuple is a salary, which is a string with a number separated by commas (Think: "50,000,000"). I need to remove the commas, so that I can typecast the string to an int. The number without a comma is being added to the list 'salaryList' but it is missing the first two digits:
eg(10,000,000 becomes 000000), and I'm not sure why.

Any other methods of doing this that are more efficient/better are more than welcome, I'm not particularly decisive on this method.

Anything more info needed I'll be happy to provide.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `int(lst[2].replace(',', ''))`…!?

Comment: @deceze thank you, I didn't realise it was that easy, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the value of tuplelist, so I have made an example one. I hope this is the right sort of thing!

```
tupleList = [[0,0,'200,000,000'],[0,1,'110,000,000']]
salaryList = [int(i[2].replace(',',''))  for i in tupleList]
```